# Is it possible to overload the Messages-Methods in GWT i18n

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, overloading

I have an `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages` implementation for a localizable GWT-Project.

But it seems that it is not possible to overload the Methods. Is it a Bug or is there a reason?

```
public interface CommonMessages extends Messages {

    public static final CommonMessages INSTANCE = GWT.create( CommonMessages.class );

    @DefaultMessage( "The entered text \"{0}\" contains the illegal character(s) \"{1}\" ." )
    String textValidatorError( String o, String e );

    @DefaultMessage( "The entered text \"{0}\" contains illegal character(s)." )
    String textValidatorError( String o );
}
```

brings up:

```
        Rebinding common.client.i18n.CommonMessages
 [java] Invoking generator com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator
 [java]    Processing interface common.client.i18n.CommonMessages
 [java]       Generating method body for textValidatorError()
 [java]          [ERROR] Argument 1 beyond range of arguments: The entered text "{0}" contains the illegal character(s) "{1}" .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Messages interface relies on a properties file. 
Because your interface has methods using the same name, gwt tries to look up the property textValidatorError twice in the same file.
The first time it's looking for a property with 2 arguments, and finds it. The second time it's looking for a property with 1 arguments, and finds one with two ... Hence the error.

Use the @Key annotation to specify different property names.

```
public interface CommonMessages extends Messages {

  public static final CommonMessages INSTANCE = GWT.create( CommonMessages.class );

  @DefaultMessage( "The entered text \"{0}\" contains the illegal character(s) \"{1}\" ." )
  String textValidatorError( String o, String e );

  @DefaultMessage( "The entered text \"{0}\" contains illegal character(s)." )
  @Key("textValidatorErrorAlternate")
  String textValidatorError( String o );
}
```